# Retrieve all fields from a list using Powershell (CSOM)

Tags: list, powershell, csom

I need to write a script which I can launch (for example) at specific time and which will make a save of all lists on the SharePoint.

For now, the script is able to connect to SharePoint and retrieve all lists name.

I need help to write the part where, for each list I retrieved with the first part, the script will retrieve all fields of all items.

I just know to do it with `hard written` columns name (like that):

```
$array =@();

foreach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
    $result = new-object psobject


    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Title -value $listItem['Title'];
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Description -value $listItem['Description'];

            [...]

    $array += $result;
}

$CsvName1 = "Export_"+$ListTitle.replace(' ','_')+".csv"
$array| export-csv $CsvName1 -Encoding unicode;
```

Is there any way to retrieve all fields for all lists just like I want?

EDIT:

Here is the full code:

```
$SiteURL = "[URL]"

Write-Host "Loading CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Write-Host "Lib. successfully loaded !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green 


$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition


$User = Read-Host -Prompt "username"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString


Write-Host "Trying to reach $SiteURL // Handling ClientContext..." -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $password) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
  $context.ExecuteQuery()
  Write-Host "Connected !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Impossible to reach $SiteURL : bad password ?" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
  return
}


$list = $web.Lists["Test Script"];
$fields = $list.Fields;

$list.Fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path ./blabla.csv;
Write-Host "Done !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
```

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0   you can try to use Get-SPOListItems and Get-SPOListFields  as a ready solution or check the code (it's a text file) for inspiration

Comment: Your question's title & body are contradictory. Can you modify it?

Comment: @grisha => Thanks for your help, but I need to use CSOM so all "Get-SP*" stuff can't work for me.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor => Which part is contradictory ? I don't understand.

Comment: @GordonAmable. These are not server cmdlets :) They are custom ones, using CSOM. Check inside the file how they are built. I think you just need to execute $lists=Get-SPOLists  ; foreach($list in $lists) {get-spolistitems $list -IncludeAllProperties }

Comment: In the title you said "Retrieve all items from a list using Powershell" but in the bottom of your question body you said "Is there any way to retrieve all fields for all lists just like I want?"

Comment: @grisha Oh great ! Sorry for being so noob I didn't understand that...
I'll try this solution, seems to be really nice. Thanks !

Comment: Np :) Let me know if it works

Comment: See my update.. It should work. I have executed it and it worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all field of a list in the following way

```
$list = $web.Lists["Your List Name"];
$fields = $list.Fields;
```

Now all fields/columns are in the `$fields`. For example, following line will save all field names into a csv file.

```
$list.Fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path $path;
```

If you are needed to read a specific field, then follow.

```
$firstName = $fields["First Name"];
```

Assuming that display name of the field is **First Name**.

**Update**

I did not notice that you have asked for CSOM. My above solution is for SOM. You need to update your script. Few things are missing in your script. I run following lines line and they gave me output

```
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tender List");
$fields = $list.Fields;
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
$context.Load($list)
$context.Load($fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path "d:\blabla.csv";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I made a few test and I just have a blank file in result... May i show you the full code ?

Comment: Yes show full code in your question

Comment: How did you do? using mine or others?

Comment: Just showed full code in question with an edit ! x)

Comment: I still have a blank file, just wanted to show you the full code then you can check if I make a good use of your code sample

Comment: Let me check. I am running your script

Comment: See my update. It should work now

Comment: Tanks you really much for your help !

Comment: Welcome my mate!