# SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, powershell, cmdlets

Is there any way to check site collection document libraries Metadata i.e. (last modified date, owner name) using SharePoint Online Shell?

Comment: Do you want for all items in the DL or just about the DL itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve all fields from a list using Powershell (CSOM)](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159749/retrieve-all-fields-from-a-list-using-powershell-csom)

Answer (score 1):

This CSOM code should help.

```
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tender List");
$fields = $list.Fields;
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
$context.Load($list)
$context.Load($fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path "d:\blabla.csv";
```

If you run the code, and replace the list title and CSV Path, it will output all the fields (including Last Modified Date and Owner Name) to a CSV File. The code can be modified to output to an array as well rather than CSV.

Comment: Can you explain how your code answers the question?

Comment: If you run the code, and replace the list title and CSV Path, it will output all the fields (including Last Modified Date and Owner Name) to a CSV File. The code can be modified to output to an array as well rather than CSV.

Comment: You should put that in your answer to improve it