# Sharepoint 2016 Powershell Script to export all fields to csv - including Created and Modified Fields

Tags: powershell, 2016, csv

I am attempting to dump all data from my Sharepoint Lists to csv.  I seem to have the code working at about 95% the way I want it, but I am missing the Created By, Created On, Modified By, and Modified On dates.  How do I capture those fields?

Here is my current code for one of my lists:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$url = "http://internalweburl/subsite"
$listName = "List1"
$path ="c:\Exports\$listname.csv"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
$fields = $list.ContentTypes | %{ $_.FieldLinks } | select Name, DisplayName
$items = @() #array to store objects representing list items
$list.items | %{ 
    $item = $_; 
    $hash = @{}; #hash table to store field name-value pairs
    $fields | %{ $hash[$_.DisplayName] = $item[$_.Name]  }; 
    $items += new-object psobject -Property $hash }
$items | Export-Csv -Path $path
```

Without having to list each individual field, I can't seem to find a way to include those.  This would be a huge undertaking as we have many lists I need to export, and I don't have the time to go through each and document all the fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$list = $web.Lists["Your List Name"];`

`$fields = $list.Fields;`

`$list.Fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path $path;`

The above should work, right using SPList.Fields ? Refer the answer here [link to answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159749/retrieve-all-fields-from-a-list-using-powershell-csom)

Comment: This just gives me a list of the column titles.  I need to export all the rows AND include the Modified/Created fields.